# Error in return statement and print statement

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling

```
from __future__ import division
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    x = raw_input().split()

    def addlist(list):
        i=0
        for entry in list:
            i = i + int(entry)
        return i


   def median (x,n):
       x.sort()
       if n%2==0:
          return (int(x[n//2]) + int(x[n//2-1])/2
       return x[(n-1)//2]  #SyntaxError: invalid syntax *1

   print (addlist(x))/n  #SyntaxError: invalid syntax *2
   print median(x,n)
```

When I remove the *1 statement from the code, output shows error in print statement *2..Please explain what's going on..I am a newbie

OUTPUT:

```
File "solution.py", line 18
return x[(n-1)//2]  #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have one extra bracket in the `return (int(x[n//2]) + int(x[n//2-1])/2` line... Either remove the starting bracket, or close it with a `)` at the end.

Comment: As with many Python errors, you want to check the line *before*. Looks like there's an extra bracket, which is why it's causing *2 to fail when *1 is removed, because it's the line above causing the problem.

Comment: @zwer Done.But it still shows the same error..

Comment: You could try evaluating the expression and storing it as a variable, then attempt to return the variable. It may help you debug the problem more effectively.

Comment: Not sure if it's the way it was pasted in here or not but the spacing is incorrect on line 13-20 needs to brought in one more space. Also removing the ( at line 16 at (int(x[n//2]) should fix the issue.